# Python how to check if an input only contains certain characters?

Tags: python

I am trying to get my code to check if a user input only contains the following characters: `"!$%^&*()_-+="`

If it contains any other characters then points should be subtracted. I tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
if "a-z" not in password and "A-Z" not in password and "0-9" not in password:
    points = points - 1
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want the "password" to **have** those characters? `"!$%^&*()_-+="` Or do you want the password to **NOT have** them? By reading your question I'd think it's the first one, but by your "code attempt" i'd have thought that you want to do otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use a regular expression by escaping the characters you listed above:

```
import re
s = "_%&&^$"
if not re.findall("^[\!\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=]+$", s):
    points -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex.

```
import re
if not (re.compile("[\"\!\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\+=\"]+").match(s)): #Subtract points
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can use regex. A generator expression like this works too:

```
points -= sum(1 for x in password if x not in '!$%^&*()_-+=')
```